# Module or template mod for making development site look different from live site

Tags: 7

When I have my development and live site open in the same browser I sometimes mix them up because they look the same.
What tricks do you all use to distinguish them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Environment Indicator](http://drupal.org/project/environment_indicator) works well for that.  It works best with a [local_settings.php](http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/stage-specific-drupal-settings-localsettingsphp) file, in my experience.